# How do I solve this issue in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

When I am testing my page in IE7, all the image have a tooltip corresponding to the text of the alt in the image tag..

```
<img src="Myimage.jpg" alt="No pic" />
```

When I hover my mouse on the displayed pic in IE7, I get a tooltip "No pic" corresponding to the text of the alt .How do I fix this ?

Comment: Install firefox... sorry, I couldn't resist.

Comment: Try hardlinking the image so http://www.yoursite.com/image.jpg as it may be the image isnt linking correctly

Comment: You need to ask yourself, are you using the `alt` attribute correctly? See my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IE6/7 treats the `alt` attribute as though it was a `title` attribute - but only if there's no actual `title` attribute set.

You can workaround it with a blank `title`:

```
<img src="Myimage.jpg" alt="No pic" title="" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try adding an empty **title** tag

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="nopic" title="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer has been posted already (empty title tag).

However, (in reference to one of the answers) alts are supposed to describe the image for 508 compliance reasons and if the image doesn't show up, so you should change the alt text to describe your picture.

I would have made a comment on the original post but SO doesn't allow me to yet.

Answer (score 0):

The actual question here is why are you using `alt` the way you are? If your image is simply decorative, you should have an empty `alt` attribute. look at the W3CS definition of the `alt` attribute.

http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/altAttribute

On this occasion is suspect youd actually want:

`<img src="Myimage.jpg" alt="" />`